# How can I detect which check-boxes were checked and then show their numbers

Tags: angularjs

I've been studying angular for three days now, and I came across a little challenge but I'm still clueless how to do solve it with Angular.js, I've searched for it, but it's really hard to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

I want to detect which checkboxes were checked and then show the number input into the inputs that their checkboxes were checked.

**Here's a drawing (pardon me for my sh*tty explanation):**

> [X] |3_____________|
>   [_] |4_____________|
>   [X] |10____________|
>   [X] |4_____________|
>   [X] |1_____________|
>   3,,10,4,1

**My code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>jQueryForm</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
  <div id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="data1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="data2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="data3" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="data4" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="data5" />
    <br/>
    <div id="data">{{data1 +","+ data2 +","+ data3 +","+ data4 +","+ data5}}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to hide those numbers in the `<div id="data">` that don't have a checked checkbox. For this, your checkboxes need an ng-model as well:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>jQueryForm</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
  <div id="form" ng-init="dataSet = [{},{},{},{},{}]">
    <div ng-repeat="data in dataSet">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.checked"/>
      <label>Data:</label>
      <input type="number" ng-model="data.number" />
      <br/>
    </div>
    
    <span ng-repeat="data in dataSet">
      <span ng-if="data.checked">{{data.number}}</span>
      <span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
    </span>
   
</body>

</html>
```

Now, I did quite a lot of things here. First, I assumed you want the solution to work for more than 5 elements. That's what the `ng-init` is for. It initializes the scope variable `dataSet` as an array of 5 objects. Of course, this should come from a controller, but to keep it to HTML here, I used `ng-init`.

Secondly, I used `ng-repeat` to iterate over the objects in `dataSet` and repeatedly create DOM objects.

Next, I gave the checkbox an `ng-model` (namely `data.checked`), which corresponds to `dataSet[$index].checked`.

Last, but not least, the output is handled in an `ng-repeat` as well - to keep it adjustable to the size of `dataSet`. `$last` is a special variable within an `ng-repeat` scope that is true if it's the last element.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is just to give you an idea of how it works. You can extend this idea. It's the `ng-if` that you have to use. `ng-if` documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

```
<div id="form">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="check1" />
<label>Data:</label>
<input type="number" ng-model="data1" />    
<span ng-if="check1">{{data1}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to deal with this. The basic idea is you have to provide the link between check box and the input field. It needs a way to show/hide input field based on checked item.

[Check this plunk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9qGRvDZePeGCTXXMTPX9?p=preview)

```
  <body ng-app="checkboxExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.dataModel={};
        $scope.checkboxOptions = {
          data1: true,
          data2: true,
          data3: true,
          data4: true,
          data5: true,
        };
        //or 
        // $scope.checkboxOptions ={}; //this will generate falsey statement for checkboxOptions.data1
      }]);
  </script>
  <div id="form" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxOptions.data1" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-if="checkboxOptions.data1" ng-model="dataModel.data1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxOptions.data2" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-if="checkboxOptions.data2" ng-model="dataModel.data2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxOptions.data3" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-if="checkboxOptions.data3" ng-model="dataModel.data3" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxOptions.data4" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-if="checkboxOptions.data4" ng-model="dataModel.data4" />
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxOptions.data5" />
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="number" ng-if="checkboxOptions.data5" ng-model="dataModel.data5" />
    <br/>
    <div id="data">{{dataModel.data1 +","+ dataModel.data2 +","+ dataModel.data3 +","+ dataModel.data4 +","+ dataModel.data5}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```